# ngFor not working in existing app, will work in newly created app

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, ngfor

I have an existing application that has a lot of hard coded values. Realizing the data does not change, I've started by creating a JSON file to be loaded at runtime.

In the existing application, if I try the code below, the application goes blank and it looks like not all models are built/deployed BUT there are no compiler issues. No problems noted. I've verified this by comparing compiled objects between my testApp and this app in debugger tools in Firefox.

I'm running macOS 10.14.6, Angular 7. Not sure what else is going to be needed.

Here is the template snippet for my code.

```
        <ul *ngFor="let urlData of Urls">
            <li>
                <a href="{{ urlData.url }}" target="_blank"><span  class="citation">{{ urlData.label }}</span></a>
            </li>
         </ul>
```

The above compiles with no issues and Visual Studio Code shows no problems.

[image]

If instead I do the following in the code,

```
 <ul>
  <li>
    <a href="{{Urls[0].url}}" target="_blank">{{Urls[0].label}}</a>
  </li>
 <li>
  <a href="{{Urls[1].url}}" target="_blank">{{Urls[1].label}}</a>
 </li>
 <li>
  <a href="{{Urls[2].url}}" target="_blank">{{Urls[2].label}}</a>
  </li>
  <li>
  <a href="{{Urls[3].url}}" target="_blank">{{Urls[3].label}}</a>
  </li>
  <li>
  <a href="{{Urls[4].url}}" target="_blank">{{Urls[4].label}}</a>
  </li>
 </ul>
```

I can access the data in my object and all is well with the world.

Created a new testApp and copied the data file, the data model and updated the app.component TS and HTML template file and it worked without an issue.

My application is using material, which the testApp does not have.

I'm at a loss and have not been able to resolve the issue or find anything like it by Google searches over the last 24 hours.

**IMPORTANT**:
Just ran a test and installed @angular/material and @angular/cdk and I get the same issue in my testApp so it seems related to them. Removing both packages restored functionality in the testApp. No other changes were made but to add them to the testApp and add the import statements needed in the app.module.ts file.

**What could be causing the *ngFor construct to fail when using @angular/material and @angular/cdk?**

Comment: As you already made a reproduction can you share it on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/)? That way we can debug it as well.

Answer (score 3):

Put the ***ngFor="let urlData of Urls"** into your li-TAGS. Your Code will produce a new ul-TAG for each Array item

Comment: Hi, that did not resolve the issue. 

Please note, I created a testApp, copied the files over to it and it runs there. The testApp does not have material or cdk installed, nor bootstrap.

Comment: Sorry. Comments can only be edited for 5 minutes and I was outside the time length.

The code builds the main but dies on polyfills. Nothing else builds either when I have the *ngFor construct in code. 

This is completely strange. As indicated, testApp, without bootstrap, material or cdk, works with the ngFor construct. But adding those items in, and resolving all external dependencies, and the ngFor construct causes the application to NOT build correctly.

Comment: Talked to a co-worker who does Angular. He believes I'm missing a materials module so I will go research that. 

Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Did not look in the browser's debugger console. Found that ngFor was not known meaning I'm missing some imports. Just need to determine what imports are missing and add them.